# I wanted my router and my server to both have different public ip addresses. ISP says that it is impossible

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

just to clarify I don't know much about networking so excuse my bad explanation. I have a server computer I just got at my office and a router. I want the server to be assigned a public ip so I can ssh into it anywhere i am and a different ip address for the router so I can connect my phone and laptop to the network. I have business internet btw. I tried calling my isp to help me achieve this and they said I would have to run a separate fiber wire in and pay for another service, and that I can't have 2 different ip addresses with one fiber wire. So I got a netgear network switch I found, plugged the ethernet coming from the isp's fiber box to it, then plugged my server and router to the network switch:

[image: see image]

So it worked and both had different public ip addresses but the download speed was much slower. I then called the isp and they were very surprised and said whatever I did, that is not supposed to happen. Can someone explain what is going on? Also, is there a good way to have a public ip to my server and have wifi? Thank you!

Comment: Your image has invalid IP addresses in it, which is not useful for us to help you. Provide real IP addresses. RFC 1918 private nets where you have those.  And only if you must obfuscate, reserved for documentation in place of public.   https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts

Comment: This may simply be the policy of the ISP, which there is nothing you can do other than to follow their policies or change ISP. There are plenty of tools that support multiple IP addresses. There are even ISP provided modems that will assign multiple public IP addresses as you have configured in your image. However, there are also modems that will automatically assign private IP addresses to devices as you have in your image, so please clarify the IP addresses as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Implement IPv6. Ask your ISP about it, and also request service where they accept you running "servers".

IPv6 allows every user to have at least a /56 or /48. Divided into /64 subnets each with effectively unlimited addresses. NAT is no longer required.

Comment: A downside to exclusive IPv6 may include failure to communicate with various services and websites that do not offer IPv6 addresses (e.g., Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites, including Server Fault).

Comment: Dual stack remains an option. IPv6 for remote access and the modern internet, IPv4 for legacy.